# Transcoding HTTP to gRPC: Same endpoint with different parameters

Tags: api, grpc, naming-conventions, transcoding

I already have a working gRPC project working. I'm looking to build an API to be able to do some HTTP requests.

I have the following 2 types:

```proto
message FindRequest {
  ModelType model_type = 1;
  oneof by {
    string id = 2;
    string name = 3;
  }
}
```

```proto
message GetAllRequest {
  ModelType model_type = 1;
  int32 page_size = 2;
  oneof paging {
    int32 page = 3;
    bool skip_paging = 4;
  }
}
```

And then, I would like to have those 2 endpoints:

```proto
  // Get a data set by ID or name. Returns an empty data set if there is no such
  // data set in the database. If there are multiple data sets with the same
  // name in the database it returns the first of these data sets.
rpc Find(FindRequest) returns (DataSet){
    option (google.api.http) = { get: "/datasets" };
 }
```

```proto
  // Get (a page of) all data sets of a given type. If no page size is given
  // (page <= 0) it defaults to 100. An unset page (page <= 0) defaults to the
  // first page.
rpc GetAll(GetAllRequest) returns (GetAllResponse){
    option (google.api.http) = { get: "/datasets" };
}
```

It makes sense to me to have 2 different endpoints with the same name, but that differ with the parameters.
For instance, requesting `/datasets?model-type=XXX` should be mapped to the `GetAll` function, while requesting `/datasets?model-type=XXX&name=YYY` should be mapped to `Find` function.
However, it doesn't work, since the mapping fails I guess, so none of these endpoints returns me anything.

I think the solution to make the mapping working would be to force the parameter to be required, however, I am working with `proto3`, which has disallowed the `required` field.

So how could I be able to have 2 endpoints with the same name, but different parameters, with proto3 ?

I know that if I am using different endpoint names, it is working, for example for the `findRequest`, I could have the following endpoint : `/findDatasets`, but regarding the best practice about API naming convention, it is not advisable, or is it ?

Answer (score 1):

The conventional way to solve this problem is to use different methods. My hunch is that it's an anti-pattern to try to differentiate using the fields in the request string.

```proto
service YourService {
    rpc FindSomething(FindSomethingRequest) returns (FindSomethingResponse){
        option (google.api.http) = { get: "/something/find" };
    }
    rpc ListSomething(ListSomethingRequest) returns (ListSomethingResponse){
        option (google.api.http) = { get: "/something/list" };
    }
}

message FindSomethingRequest {
  ModelType model_type = 1;
  string id = 2;
  string name = 3;
}
message ListSomethingRequest {
  int32 page_size = 2;
  int32 page_token = 3;
}
message ListSomethingResponse {
  repeated ModelType model_types = 1;
  int32 page_size = 2;
  int32 next_page_token = 3;
}
```

I'm unsure of your underlying thing structure but, I think it's better practice to model things with all possible properties and permit leaving some unset (e.g. either `id` or `name` or possibly both in `FindSomethingRequest`) rather than creating different message types for all possible queries. You model the thing not how you interact with it.

In your implementation (!) of `FindSomething`, you then deal with the permutations of how users of the message may construct the fields. Perhaps reporting an error "Either `id` or `name` is required`.

I think `ListSomething`'s messages could be simpler too. You request a List of (ModelTypes) and give a `page_size` and an `page_token` (that could be `""`). It returns a list of `ModelType`s, the size of the page returned (possibly less than requested) and a `next_page_token` if there is more data, that you can use to make the next `ListSomething` request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is actually working, but I read that it is better to avoid having verbs in the API endpoints. However, if this is the only way to make it works, I will do this way!